# Protractor - readline not waiting for input

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor

I'm trying to use readline to capture input from the console, but my code is not waiting for the input. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? The code just blows right through, and doesn't allow any input.

```
var readline = require('readline');

it('Input Check Number to Search for', function(){
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.question("Enter Check Number: ", function(answer){
    console.log("Answer = " + answer);
    missingCheckNum = answer;
    rl.close();
  });
});
```

Solution that worked for me:

```
it('Input Check Number to Search for', async function(){

  const ans = await askQuestion("Enter missing check number "); 

  console.log("Missing check number is = " + ans);
  missingCheckNum = ans;
});

function askQuestion(query) {
  var readline = require('readline');

  var rl = null;
  rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    terminal: false 
  });

  return new Promise(resolve => rl.question(query, ans => {
    rl.close();
    resolve(ans);
  }))
}
```

Comment: Removed the [selenium] tag since there's no reference to it in the question.

Comment: Can you use Protractor without Selenium?

Comment: No idea. I don't use protractor. Your overall project may involve all these different libraries but you should tag your question based on what libraries are required to repro the issue stated in your question.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: After another full day of tinkering, I found some code that worked. I'll update my post with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the `rl.question` function ends before its callback, and so `rl` variable goes out of scope. You should define `rl` var before you call `it` function (or globally).